# How I can remove navigation bar background with appearance in the iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, ios13

I am tried to remove the navigation bar background in iOS 13 in the if's statements with #available. I know the original code to remove the navigation bar background for iOS 12 and older iOS in the else's statements. However, Apple did announce a new system called **Appearance** in anywhere to support that new iOS 13 system.

```
    let app = UINavigationBarAppearance()

    let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar

    app.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    app.shadowImage = UIImage()


    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = app

    navigationBar!.standardAppearance = app
    navigationBar!.scrollEdgeAppearance = app
```

I believe this configureWithOpaqueBackground() allows us to remove the navigation bar background, But I test on iOS 13.1 simulator appear black navigation bar background. I know what caused it.

```
     app.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
     app.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
     app.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
     app.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1603881121, green: 0.1677560508, blue: 0.2133775949, alpha: 1)
```

That code allows us to put the custom color on the black background. I ready to add that code in the viewWillDisappear's statements to restore the navigation bar background to normal color background before `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = app` with remove  `app.configureWithOpaqueBackground()` and  `app.shadowImage = UIImage()`. Now, I need to create the translucent navigation bar background in the viewWillAppear's statements, but it can't see any translucent background due to the black background still display.

I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem! :)

Comment: I'm not understanding the goal. Is it that you want the background of the navigation to be clear (completely transparent and invisible) under all circumstances? Is it that you always want it to be white? What?

Comment: That is one what I am look for this background of the navigation to be clear. I apologize for this post get you a bit confusing. I am still learning a English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the navigation bar to become completely transparent:

```
    let app = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    app.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = app
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = app
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = app
```

Do not mess with the `isTranslucent` of the navigation bar.

Comment: Bingo! BTW: I was upload that UIImage in the wrong layer. Now, it was prefect transparent! I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem! :D

Comment: I'm not sure if it's always necessary, but it didn't take effect until I added a navigationController.setNeedsLayout() after setting the standardAppearance, etc. Our navigation controller is in a UISplitViewController and the above code is in the viewDidLoad method, so that may be part of it.

Comment: @LenK Thanks, that's a valuable comment. Yes, I've experienced difficulties getting layout to behave properly in a split view controller too, so that may well have something to do with it.